# Huge text file to small excel files

Tags: python, csv, export-to-excel, text-mining, xlrd

I have a huge text file (4 GB), where each "line" is of the syntax:
`[number] [number]_[number] [Text]`.
For example

```
123 12_14 Text 1
1234 13_456 Text 2
33 12_12 Text 3
24 678_10 Text 4
```

My purpose is to have this data saved as Excel file, where each "line" in the text file,
is a row in the excel file. According to the past example:

```
[A1] 123
[B1] 12_14
[C1] Text 1
[A2] 1234
[B2] 13_456
[C2] Text 2
[A3] 33
[B3] 12_12
[C3] Text 3
[A4] 24
[B4] 678_10
[C4] Text 4
```

My plan is to iterate the text "lines", as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18178159/1869297), separate the "lines",
and save to the cells in an excel file.

Because of the text size issue, I thought to create many small excel files, which all together will be equal to the text file.

Than I need to analyze the small excel files, mainly found terms that where mentioned in the `[Text]` cells, and count the number of apperance, related to the `[number]` cells (representing a post and ID of a post).

Finally, I need to sum all this data in an excel file.

I'm considering the best way to create and analyze the excel files.
As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3239207/1869297) the main libraries are [xlrd](http://www.python-excel.org/) and [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Comment: If your only goal is to analyze the original text file (things like counting stuff...), then this is very much **not** the easiest way to do it.  If you have some other reason for ending up with a bunch of excel files, then carry on.

Comment: You don't need to load the whole text file into memory, you can just [read the text line by line](http://www.yak.net/fqa/171.html). The splitted up text as excel is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Brionius I'm pretty sure I don't have other options than small excel files, but what will be the another approach?

Comment: @simpleBob the code suggested (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178089/parsing-big-text-file-using-regex/18178159#18178159) dosen't load the whole text into memory

Comment: @pnuts It was a beginner's mistake, sorry.

Comment: @user1869297 - it's hard to say what another approach would be unless I know what your actual goal is - if you can clarify what the end-goal of this whole business is, we can help you find the best way.

Comment: read a file line by line in excel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528694/read-parse-text-file-line-by-line-in-vba/11528932#11528932

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I'm pretty sure I don't have other options than small excel files, but what will be the another approach?"

Your huge text file is a type of database, although an inconvenient one. A bunch of small Excel files are another, even less convenient representation of the same database. I assume you are looking to make a bunch of small files because Excel has an upper limit on how many rows it can contain (65'000 or 1'000'000 depending on the version of Excel). However, as has [been noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16770616/282912), Excel files are truly horrible database stores.

Since you are already using Python, use module [`sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), it's already built in and it's a real database, and it can handle more than a million rows. And it's fast.

But I wanted to get an idea how fast it is with data on the scale that you propose so I created a 30M row database of roughly the same complexity as your dataset. The schema is simple:

```
create table words
    (id integer primary key autoincrement not null,
     first text, second text, third text);
```

and populated it with random trigrams drawn from /usr/dict/words (I have a module for generating test data like this which makes entries that look like

```
sqlite> select * from words limit 5;
1|salvation|prorates|bird
2|fore|embellishment|empathized
3|scalier|trinity|graze
4|exes|archways|interrelationships
5|voguish|collating|partying
```

but a simple query for a row I knew was near the end took longer than I'd hoped:

```
select * from words where first == "dole" and second == "licked";
29599672|dole|licked|hates
```

took about 7 seconds on a pretty average 3-year-old desktop so I added a couple of indexes

```
create index first on words (first);
create index second on words (second);
```

which did double the size of the database file from 1.1GB to 2.3GB but brought the simple query time down to a rather reasonable 0.006 second. I don't think you'll do as well with Excel.

So parse your data however you must, but then put it in a real database.

Answer (score 0):

What is the issue with just looping through the file line by line? If you have your heart set on excel I would reccomend [openpyxl](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/).